# Set custom image to checkbox without mandatory label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a project where sometimes checkboxes don't have labels. The only way of setting custom image for checkbox I've found was setting image for `label:before` for corresponding `label` which has `for` value with `id` of checkbox.

Are there any CSS way (at least hacky) to set custom image to checkbox without changing markup? `input[type="checkbox"]:before` works only in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found that works everywhere except IE is via setting CSS `appearance`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Sorry are you saying it does or does NOT work in Edge? Not even Microsoft cares about EOL IE but they do care about Edge which I think is basically open source Chromium.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It worked in Edge even in 2017. It wasn't Chromium-based back then.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to do it without label for all browsers. In my opinion label is necessarily.

But you can use JS for this and one of library like [icheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) (and [many other](https://www.sitepoint.com/15-jquery-radio-button-checkbox-style-plugins/) not only jQuery also pure JS)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you add a container to your checkbox like this

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

and then

```
div{
    position: relative;
    /* Your custom style */
}

input{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. And how are you going to check/uncheck this? Can you add running snippet? 2. Wrapping checkbox in container adds extra complexity to markup. Why this way is better than adding extra labels?